# How to remove space between custom figure caption and auto-generated number in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown, figure

I'm trying to change the figure captions in my RMarkdown file to have the repeated style of "Figure S1", "Figure S2", and so on. To do this, I tried running the following basic code in RMarkdown:

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Shawn Hemelstrand"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  pdf_document
header-includes:
- \usepackage{caption}
- \captionsetup[figure]{name=Figure S}
---

```{r plot,echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Some informative description."}
plot(iris$Petal.Width,
     iris$Petal.Length)
```
````

However, you can see from the output below that it creates an unnecessary space between the "S" and the number of the figure.

[image]

I want "S1" here and not "S 1". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [redefine the figure's counter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305302/how-to-customize-the-figure-numbering-with-a-letter-or-special-symbol), e.g.

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Shawn Hemelstrand"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
format:
  pdf:
    fig-labels: 
header-includes:
- \usepackage{caption}
- \setcounter{figure}{0}
- \renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
---

```{r plot,echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Some informative description."}
plot(iris$Petal.Width,
     iris$Petal.Length)
```
````

**Result**:

[image]